# google maps api places autocomplete getPlace() not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have problem with google maps api places autocomplete. It seems that function `getPlaces()` not working as described in documentation:
[Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete)

> Returns the details of the Place selected by user if the details were
>   successfully retrieved. Otherwise returns a stub Place object, with
>   the name property set to the current value of the input field.

Taking a following code as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    initialize = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('locationsearch');
        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)']
        };
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    submitform = function () {
        searchplace = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(searchplace.name);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="submitform();return false;">
        <input type="text" id="locationsearch"/>
        <input type="button" value="search" onclick="submitform(); return false;"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This simple code uses autocomplete feature in `input="text"` element and after button next to it is pressed it should log place name in console.
Problem I have is when `input` element has incomplete place selected. I expect a `getPlace()` function to return `place` object with a name property set to a current value of `input` element. Instead console is logging error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong using places autocomplete or is this function simply not working correctly?
Thank You.

Comment: please define "incomplete place selected"

Comment: It's when you write couple of letters into input element and you don't pick anything from autocomplete list. Location is't selected but input element is't empty too.

Comment: The documentation decribes this behaviour only for the case when the enter-key has been pressed in the input.

Comment: that's not true

documentation of 3.14:

"Returns the details of the Place selected by user if the details were successfully retrieved. Otherwise returns a stub Place object, with the name property set to the current value of the input field."

I have the very same problem. This needs to be workarounded by getting of direct value of connected input field...

Comment: That is a case, and I rebuild a whole `autocomplete` function to work as intended. I did not found any other solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Reason being Google has used another identifier '**locality**' instead of usual 'name'.

So if you use the sub element 'locality' from 'place', **you can** get the name of the place.

Code:

```
 var val = place.address_components[0][componentForm['locality']];
```

[Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)